# Get text value passed to valueBinding in Ember.TextField (ember-validations)

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing an extension to `Ember.TextField` to change the class of the text field if the parent object is invalid. I'm using the [ember-validations library](https://github.com/lcoq/ember-validations) to do the validations on my ember-data object. I have this working right now, but I'd love to be able to do it without passing in the `validationMethod` variable. How can I get just the text string passed in to `valueBinding` from within the view?

**address.js.coffee**

```
App.Address = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations,
  street_1: DS.attr('string')
  street_2: DS.attr('string')
  ...

  validations:
    street_1:
      presence: true
)
```

**validated_text_field.js.coffee**

```
Ember.ValidatedTextField = Ember.TextField.extend(
  validationMethod: null
  classNameBindings: 'error'

  focusOut: ->
    object = @get('controller').get('content')
    object.validateProperty(@get('validationMethod'))

  error: (->
    object = @get('controller').get('content')
    if object.get("isValid")
      return false
    else
      error_keys = object.get("validationErrors." + @get('validationMethod') + ".keys")
      if error_keys
        return error_keys.length > 0
      else
        return false
  ).property('controller.content.isValid')
)
```

**edit.handlebars**

```
{{view Ember.ValidatedTextField validationMethod="street_1" valueBinding="street_1" id="street_1" placeholder="Street 1" required="true"}}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't suggest it because it's internal code, you can get the strings from the bindings themselves.

```
validationMethod = @get("valueBinding._from").split(".").get("lastObject")
```

Check out how we handle the label for Ember-Bootstrap for another example: https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/packages/ember-bootstrap/lib/forms/field.js